# How to use $dz=d[r(t)(\cos t + i\sin t)]$ as a change of coordinates?

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, differential

This notation comes in handy for some path integrals, but I don't know yet how this is calculated. Is it simply a change of coordinates?

> Is this correct: $$z=r(t)(\cos t+i\sin t) \quad t\in\mathbb{R}/2\pi. \\
> \Rightarrow dz=d[r(t)](\cos t + i\sin t)+r(t)[d(\cos t + i\sin t)]  
> \\=[r'(t)(\cos t + i\sin t)+r(t)(-\sin t+i\cos t)]\,dt?$$

Or may be better:

> How do I express $dz$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: It should better be $dz = d \big( r(\cos t + i \sin t) \big) = dr(\cos t +i \sin t)+ r.d(\cos t + i \sin t)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct for the special case of a path that parametrises (a part of) the circle with radius $r$ around $0$ (in a particular way, it can be parametrised differently).

Generally, if you have a (piecewise) differentiable path $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ and a function defined and continuous (the latter can be relaxed) on the trace of $\gamma$, then the integral

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$$

is *defined* as

$$\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\, dt,$$

where the latter is the ordinary Riemann- or Lebesgue-integral (or whatever integration theory you prefer) of the function $t\mapsto f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)$ over the interval $[a,b]$ [the function may not be defined in finitely many points, since $\gamma$ is only piecewise differentiable, but neither the Riemann nor the Lebesgue integral notice if you arbitrarily define the function in these points].

A catchy way of memorising that is to say that $dz = \gamma'(t)\,dt$ for $z = \gamma(t)$ (and viewing it as differential forms gives a formal justification, $\gamma'(t)\,dt$ is the pull-back of $dz$ by $\gamma$).

Comment: Your last observation is what I'm trying to be able to deal with. How catchy is it to memorize $dz=\gamma ' (t)\, dt$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that question. It's formally not quite correct, since $dz$ is a differential form (or you can also interpret it as a complex measure, to complicate the picture) on (a subset of) $\mathbb{C}$, while $\gamma'(t)\,dt$ is a differential form (or complex measure) on an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. But in effect, when you integrate, you get the pull-back $\gamma^\ast(dz)$, and that _is_ $d(\gamma(t)) = \gamma'(t)\,dt$.